# Celery task calling another task

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

I have two files. One is the main file of my programm and it has all celery tasks that have to be done:

```
chord(
    tasks.task_01.subtask(task_id='task_01'),
    tasks.task_02.subtask(task_id='task_02')
).delay()
```

Then I have a task.py file:

```
@task(bind=True)
def task_01(self, result=None):

    headers = models.Header.objects.all()
    group(extract_emails.subtask((header,)) for header in headers).delay()
```

And finally the extract_emails taks:

```
@task(bind=True)
def extract_emails(header, result=None):

    print header.id  #to check in celery log if the header item is recieved
    url_parser.find_emails(header)
```

So my goal is to execute task_01 so that it runs a set of 'extract_emails' tasks in parallel with the 'header' as an argument.
I expect 'extract_emails' task to recieve this header and run some simple code with it.

When Im trying to do it I get:
AttributeError("'extract_emails' object has no attribute 'id'",)

Where does it come from?? Im not even passing the name of the task as an argument! What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

In my particular example 'extract_emails' task should be written this way:

```
@task(bind=True)
def extract_emails(self, result=None):

    header = self.request.args[1] 
    url_parser.find_emails(header)
```

Just use self.request.PARAM to extract what you need. 
More information you can find in [official docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html).